# Different results when using isNode(_:insideFrustumOf:) vs nodesInsideFrustum(of:)

Tags: ios, arkit

Have a quick question to see if I'm using isNode(_:insideFrustumOf:) correctly.

I'm putting an node (SCNNode) into an ARSCNView with standard configuration.  The geometry in the node is off-centered so I used the node's pivot property to adjust its center point.

```
let c = object.boundingSphere.center            
object.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(c.x, c.y, c.z)
object.position = c
```

My issue arises after I update the object's scale or rotation using a pinch gesture.  After this happens, I get different results from isNode(_:insideFrustumOf:) and from nodesInsideFrustum(of:).

The node I'm testing is clearly visible in the screen, but isNode(_:insideFrustumOf:) fails to see it.  However, the node is in the [SCNNode] results from nodesInsideFrustum(of:).

My question is whether this is a bug, or is there some other proper way of centering geometry to a node that may fix this issue.  For now, I'm going to use the nodesInsideFrustum(of:) function and test if the object is in the array.

Thanks!

Comment: were you able to find a solution for the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is making sure you are using the ”presentation” node for any moving objects, even the pointOfView if it’s moving.

This is a working snippet from my app inside the renderer: (updateAtTime)

```
if renderer.isNode(stationaryObjectNode, insideFrustrumOf: renderer.pointOfView!.presentation) == true {
    //do stuff if seen
}
```

If your object is not stationary, use `movingObject.presentation` instead of `stationaryObjectNode`

Comment: Nice, I'll give that a try.  Thanks for the answer.